# Why TextRenderer is not drawing Wingdings font in Usercontrol?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

It is easier to explain my question with an example than with words.

This is my UserControl1 code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {

    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {

        public UserControl1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
            Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "à", new Font("Wingdings", 12), new Point(10, 10), Color.Black);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "à", Font, new Point(30, 10), Color.Black);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "à", new Font(Font.Name, Font.Size), new Point(50, 10), Color.Black);
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I add this control to a form and set its Font property to Wingdings 12.
The second TextRenderer line doesn't draw a right arrow, but simply "à".
The third line does draw an arrow, exactly as the first one does.

Maybe I am missing some setting, can someone explain that, please?

Comment: Hard to see the problem, no compelling reason I see for the font mapper to step in.  But ugh, -100 elegance points for not overriding OnPaint, not using e.Graphics and not disposing the font.

Comment: Answering as a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

You created a Wingdings `Font` object in the first DrawText() function call, but you don't save that object for use in the second and third DrawText() function calls, so they are reverting back to a default font. Specifically, they're using the `this.Font` object, which is the font set for your UserControl.

To fix this, you need to save the Wingdings `Font` object in a variable, and then re-use it on each call to DrawText().

Also, you should not be calling the CreateGraphics() function inside of a Paint event handler. The Paint event handler already gets a `Graphics` object to draw into passed as a member of the `PaintEventArgs`. That will be more efficient, and also simpler, because you don't need to bother with disposing it.

When you *do* need to dispose something (like a `Font` object), it is better to wrap it in a `using` statement. This ensures that it will be *automatically* disposed, without you having to worry about calling Dispose() yourself or in the event of an exception.

So, taking these points into account, you should rewrite your code to:

```
private void UserControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    using (Font f = new Font("Wingdings", 12)) {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "à", f, new Point(10, 10), Color.Black);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "à", f, new Point(30, 10), Color.Black);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "à", f, new Point(50, 10), Color.Black);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you *always* wanted your UserControl to draw text using Wingdings, you could just set that font as the control's Font:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {

    public UserControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Font = new Font("Wingdings", 12);
    }

    private void UserControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "à", this.Font, new Point(10, 10), Color.Black);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "à", this.Font, new Point(30, 10), Color.Black);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "à", this.Font, new Point(50, 10), Color.Black);
    }
}
```

I think this will be slightly more efficient, because it doesn't need to create a new `Font` object each time the control gets painted.

Comment: Thank you for your considerations about the code efficiency. The first call to DrawText(), however, was placed just for comparison. I have set the UserControl Font property in the Form designer to Wingdings 12, so this should be `this.Font`. And in fact is, since in the third call `new Font(Font.Name, Font.Size)` results in Wingdings 12, which is correctly drawn.

Answer (score -1):

I have changed my code to the "elegant" format:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {

    public UserControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (Font f1 = new Font("Wingdings", 12))
        using (Font f2 = new Font(Font.Name, Font.Size)) {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "à", f1, new Point(10, 10), Color.Black);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "à", Font, new Point(30, 10), Color.Black);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "à", f2, new Point(50, 10), Color.Black);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This makes absolutely no change in the result!
In the first and third calls DrawText() draws an arrow, in the second call it draws "à".